# How to handle proxies when using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, proxy, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm facing some trouble when using the class **QNetworkAccessManager**.

I use it to download a simple file from an url like "http://www.foo.com/bar/foobar.txt".

When I start a download I use :

```
m_pNetworkReply = m_pNetworkAccessManager->get(QNetworkRequest(m_CurrentFileToDownload));
```

Then I connect a few slots to receive, for example, errors during the process of downloading the file.

My problem is, if the computer is using a proxy, how do I manage to know it ? I've seen the class **QNetworkProxy** but how do I initialise it ?

Is there a way to match the settings of the default browser ? Do I have to let the user configure himself the proxy ?

I hope my question is clear...

Thanks in advance for your help and advices !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into these functions:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkproxyfactory.html#systemProxyForQuery
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setProxyFactory